# Do you need a landscape iPad launch image for app thats just portrait

Tags: ios, ipad

I have made me app so that device orientation is portrait only, however there it still has a place to put landscape launch image. Will I have to have one? If so can I just have a rotated version of the portrait one (i.e. this will be sideways if the device is held in a landscape manner)?

Comment: Nope. You don't need it.

Comment: @Totumus Maximus So even though theres the option I can leave it blank and it will be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a landscape default image even if you do support landscape.

If you are only in portrait, then a single image will do.